# Is there simple “angularJS” way using ng-repeat directive, to replace characters in object.name string with other character directly?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

If the object's property name is `Bob_Kenneth_Frank` (as actual value) to `Bob Kenneth Frank` (displayed output)

I unsuccessfully tried different variants of:

**html**

```
ng-repeat="myChange(person.name) in persons"
```

**in controller**

```
function myChange(name){
    return name.replace(/_/g, " ")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom `filter`.

See a **[working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/MKE5N0y4NX8PsledZjGc)**.

```
angular.module('app').filter('replaceUnderscoreBySpace', function () {
  return function (input) {
      return input.replace(/_/g, ' ');
  };
});
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in y">
  {{x | replaceUnderscoreBySpace}}
</div>
```

Explanations on **[Todd Motto Blog](https://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/)**

Comment: it works, i didn't know about custom filters. thank you!